# It is possible to make the preview/ slider/ navigator in Highcharts to match the graph?

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts, navigation

[image]

The three lines in the slider/ navigator are not similar at all with the graph. It is anything I can do to fix this? I didn't find anything in the documentation and I want to keep this library in my project, but it isn't a good experience for the user to see something totally wrong in the preview. Thanks!

The code is standard:

```
function createChart() {
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },

        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                }
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent',
                showInNavigator: true
            }
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    }); }

$.each(names, function (i, name) {

    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json',    function (data) {

        seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data
        };

        seriesCounter += 1;

        if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
            createChart();
        }
    }); });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigator is just showing the *real* data :

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            //compare: 'percent',
            showInNavigator: true
        }
    },
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/ws0Lmgvb/)

Comment: Thank you a lot! I knew that the series compared by the percent allow the comparison of the values against the first value in the visible range, but I wasn't aware it is such a difference. I'm not even sure I find relevant this option anymore.